# iphone css and html banner like iads

Tags: jquery-mobile, iphone

hi i am working on a iphone website  with http://jquerymobile.com/ on one part i want to show a banner like iphone free apps show's a small banner under the page on top of everything and scroll with content i get it working on fixed on one place but its not scrolling with the page

```
 <div style="position:fixed; top:320px; left:10px;">
     <img src="templates/banner.jpg"   />
 </div>
```

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: can you give an example link so we can visually see it? Mobile link as well, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because iOS currently does not support `position:fixed`

Edit_: You could use iScroll JS to get this done. http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Edit2: Starting with iOS5, `position: fixed` is supported.